# How to know the Macro context you are in

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

For Example:

```
#define MY_TEST_FUNCTION
#ifdef MY_TEST_FUNCTION
void __MACRO_NAME##_TEST (void *)
{

}
#endif
```

This should produce:

```
#ifdef MY_TEST_FUNCTION
void MY_TEST_FUNCTION_TEST (void *)
{

}
#endif
```

This is something like **func**, where we get the function name inside a function. Is this possible?

Comment: Unclear for me. Do you want a preprocessor? `__func__` is not ok?

Comment: I want to get the Macro name from with the ifdef.

Comment: Which macro name ?  The one contained by `_TEST` ? just type `_TEST`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such placeholder defined in the language standard.

You *know* the macro you just checked, though, so I do not see how such a placeholder would be useful even if it existed.

Also consider...

```
#if defined( FOO ) || defined( BAR )
```

...what should the "context" be named as?

Comment: Thanks, got it. I was trying to find a way not to type the MACRO name again, instead use something inbuild. Just like __func__.

Answer (score 1):

You assume too much of the macro inclusion system.  A (without-variable) macro simply replace a name with a string of character.  There is not "current macro context", just a map of macro names with their replacement characters. There is nothing more special about the header macro protection than any macro like`EXIT_FAILURE` (in `stdlib.h`).

`#ifdef` and `#ifndef` just test whether a macro, any macro, is defined with a given name.

So if you want to have a "header macro context", you have to manually set it at the beginning of the header.

Or maybe your problem could be solve with a parameter macro.

```
#define function_variation( suffix ) int function_##suffix() {\
  ... \
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Asingle macro for one type of function is enough

```
#define FUNCTION(macroname,prefix) void macroname##prefix() {//func definition }
#define FUNCTION(MY_TEST_FUNCTION,test)
```